# How to save changes to Windows group using WMI and Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

Using Powershell, I retrieve a Windows group with WMI. Then I try to modify a property and update the object but it fails (see error message below). What's wrong ?

```
$group = Get-WmiObject Win32_Group -Filter ("Domain='{0}' and Name='{1}'" -f $env:ComputerName, $groupName)
$group.Description = $newDescription
$group.Put()
```

Error :
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Provider is not capable of the attempted operation " ---> System.Management
.ManagementException: Provider is not capable of the attempted operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `Description` property of `Win32_Group` objects is read-only. Use the [ADSI WinNT provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
$group = [adsi]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/$groupName,group"
$group.Description = $newDescription
$group.SetInfo()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! I did not imagine the Description property might be read-only and I focused on the put method.